# Resizing a named range deletes the range's Name structure

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, named-ranges

Whenever I try to either resize or otherwise change the cell location for a range, e.g. "A1:B1" to "A1:B2" the Name structure associated with the range is deleted. a watch entry for *range*.Name will be shown in the value column as

Application-defined or object-defined error

This does not seem to matter whether there is a name associated with it or not. In fact, changing the Name by means of *RefersTo =* automatically deletes the name structure. The following code was derived from the answer to Question 11031891, *How do I redefine a named range with VBA?*

```
    Option Explicit

Enum eColumn
  FIRSTCOLUMN = 1
  SECONDCOLUMN = 2
End Enum

Enum eRow
  FIRSTROW = 1
  SECONDROW = 2
End Enum

  Public Const scFred As String = "Fred"
  Public Const scFreda As String = "Freda"

  Public Const scAbsoluteValueRange As String = "AbsoluteValueRange"
  Public Const scResizeRange As String = "ResizeRange"

Sub ResizeIt()

  Dim iRow As Integer
  Dim nAbsoluteValue As Name
  Dim nResize As Name
  Dim rAbsoluteValue As Range
  Dim rResize As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = ActiveSheet

  '      ****                   Create Ranges                    ***

  ws.Names.Add Name:=scAbsoluteValueRange, RefersTo:=Cells(FIRSTROW, FIRSTCOLUMN)
  ws.Names.Add Name:=scResizeRange, RefersTo:=Cells(SECONDROW, SECONDCOLUMN)
  Set rAbsoluteValue = Range(scAbsoluteValueRange)
  Set rResize = Range(scResizeRange)
  Set nAbsoluteValue = ws.Names.Item(scAbsoluteValueRange)
  Set nResize = ws.Names.Item(scResizeRange)

  '      ****                   Change Ranges                    ***

  ' give an absolute reference:
  With nAbsoluteValue
    .RefersTo = ws.Cells(SECONDROW, FIRSTCOLUMN)
  End With

  iRow = FIRSTROW
  rAbsoluteValue(iRow) = scFred

  ' or, resize relative to old reference:
  With nResize
    .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Offset(-1).Resize(2).Select
  End With

  iRow = FIRSTROW
  rResize(iRow) = scFreda

End Sub
```

If I run the code as far as  the end of the 'Create Ranges phase I obtain two ranges:

AbsoluteValue occupying "A1"
Resize occupying "B2"

The watch window confirms this

Watch : + :   nAbsoluteValue : "=Sheet1!$A$1" : Name/Name : Module1.ResizeIt

Watch : + :   rAbsoluteValue.Name : "=Sheet1!$A$1" : Variant/Object/Name : Module1.ResizeIt

Watch : + :   nResize : "=Sheet1!$B$2" : Name/Name : Module1.ResizeIt

Watch : + : rResize.Name : "=Sheet1!$B$2" : Variant/Object/Name : Module1.ResizeIt

I then change the location, by use of the Name object, of **AbsoluteValue** to "A2"

In the Watch window I get

Watch : + :   nAbsoluteValue : "=Sheet1!$A$2" : Name/Name : Module1.ResizeIt

Watch :   :   rAbsoluteValue.Name :  : Variant/Integer : Module1.ResizeIt

However when I try to write to cell, "A2" (what should be the first row in the range), the result, *Fred*, goes in "A1". In other words the range location hasn't shifted
ed
For the Resize range I get a similar result:

Watch : + :   nResize : "=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2" : Name/Name : Module1.ResizeIt

Watch :   : rResize.Name :  : Variant/Integer : Module1.ResizeIt

However when I try to write to cell, "B1" (what should be the first row in the range), the result, *Freda*, goes in "B2". Again, the range location hasn't shifted

The Name Manager indicates that the cells have altered to the correct location in both instances

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to follow but I don't see any problems:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim theName As Name

    Set theName = ActiveSheet.Names.Add(Name:="myName", RefersTo:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))

    showIt theName  '>> Name:Sheet1!myName          Address:$A$1

    theName.RefersTo = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B3")

    showIt theName  '>> Name:Sheet1!myName          Address:$B$1:$B$3

    theName.RefersTo = theName.RefersToRange.Resize(6, 4)

    showIt theName  '>> Name:Sheet1!myName          Address:$B$1:$E$6

End Sub

Sub showIt(nm As Name)
    Debug.Print "Name:" & nm.Name, "Address:" & nm.RefersToRange.Address
End Sub
```

BTW this looks like a typo:

```
.RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Offset(-1).Resize(2).Select
```

`Select` doesn't belong there

**EDIT**
You do this:

```
 Set rResize = Range(scResizeRange)
```

now `rResize` points to the range defined in `scResizeRange`, but *there's no link* between `rResize` and your named range - the two are independent.  So if you change the named range and then later do this:

```
 rResize(iRow) = scFreda
```

...then it would be expected that you'd write to the original location of the named range

Comment: Tim, thanks for replying to this question promptly as you did to another of my recent questions on a different issue

Comment: **firstly**,thanks for replying to this question promptly as you did to another of my recent questions on a different issue. **Secondly**, I realise that had I used Debug.Print instead of inputting the Watch data that would have made things easier to follow. **Thirdly**, apologies for not removing Select. I thought that I had done so. Unfortunately, you seem to have confirmed what I thought unless I'm missing something fundamental. The ranges as denoted by rResize are pre-existing within the worksheet ...

Comment: So given what you have said about the Name and Range objects being independent (although I think I showed in my post that a change to the Name object causes a change to that of the Range) how do I alter the bearing of the Range object so that _rResize(iRow) = scFreda_ does write to the intended cell. Should I delete the range object and recreate each time I want to change its boundaries? Many thanks for your patience.

Comment: If you want to change the range referred to by the named range then you *need to use the name to get to that new range*.  You used `rResize`, which was a just pointer to the *old* Range, and has no connection to the name object